# What's the device - S4L85H1X01 IC by Samsung?

Tags: integrated-circuit, datasheet

I found S4L85H1X01 IC by Samsung in HP PSC 1310 (Q5763A) inkjet printer / scanner and can not obtain proper datasheet. What's that device? It's in TSSOP-20 package.

Comment: Custom component for some OEM?

Comment: The bad thing is that no service manual exists for HP PSC 1310 inkjet printer also...

Comment: It's not meant to be serviced, it's just a mean to sell consumables.